# How to use the purrr::map() in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Recently I got to know that the `map` function from `purrr` package is really powerful and tried to find out how to use it in the following case:

Using iris dataset and using `purrr::map` function, calculate `max`, `mean`, `min` for all variables `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`, respectively for each `Species` (setosa, versicolor, virginica). Then put the results into a list having

- a character: Species name, and
- four vectors: `max`, `mean`, `min` for `Sepal.Length`, `Sepal.Width`, `Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`.

Any suggestions? I was using `dplyr::mutate`, but the result format is not what I want.

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(MinSL=min(Sepal.Length),
            MaxSL=max(Sepal.Length),
            MeanSL=mean(Sepal.Length),
            MinPL=min(Petal.Length),
            MaxPL=max(Petal.Length),
            MeanPL=mean(Petal.Length))
```

It will be also nice see if there is a solution using `dpylr` to do the task. Thank you!

Comment: Why not take a look at the [purrr tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/)? There are plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need purrr. Try:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width),
               c("min", "max", "mean"))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  Species    Sepal.Length_min Sepal.Width_min Petal.Length_min Petal.Width_min
  <fct>                 <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>           <dbl>
1 setosa                 4.30            2.30             1.00           0.100
2 versicolor             4.90            2.00             3.00           1.00 
3 virginica              4.90            2.20             4.50           1.40 
# ... with 8 more variables: Sepal.Length_max <dbl>, Sepal.Width_max <dbl>,
#   Petal.Length_max <dbl>, Petal.Width_max <dbl>, Sepal.Length_mean <dbl>,
#   Sepal.Width_mean <dbl>, Petal.Length_mean <dbl>, Petal.Width_mean <dbl>
```

Comment: You could even use `summarise_all`as the summarising function is not applied to the grouping variable.